# Multiple GROUP BY and select value dependent on result of the first GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

I got the following database table:

```
combination_id  |   weight  |   group   |   std
-------------------------------------------------
    1           |   50      |   3       |   7   
    2           |   30      |   3       |   19
    3           |   30      |   3       |   19
    4           |   25      |   4       |   7
```

I group the entries by the columns **group** and **std** and sum up the values of the **weight** column:

```
SELECT SUM(weight) as weight_sum, group, std FROM weight_table 
WHERE combination_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY group, std
ORDER BY weight_sum DESC;
```

The result looks like this:

```
    weight  |   group   |   std
-----------------------------------------------
    60      |   3       |   19  
    50      |   3       |   7
    25      |   4       |   7
```

Now I want do to a second GROUP BY, but only on the **group** column, and sum over the **weight** column. The value of the **std** column in the result should be the value of the **std** column of the entry with the highest weight and the same group from the last query.
So for group **3** I want the **19** to be selected for **std**, as **60** was the highest **weight** for group **3**:

```
    weight  |   group   |   std
-----------------------------------------------
    110     |   3       |   19  
    25      |   4       |   7
```

How can I achieve this?
I am using sqlite 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
SELECT SUM(weight) as weight_sum, group, max(std) as std FROM weight_table 
WHERE combination_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
GROUP BY group
ORDER BY weight_sum DESC;
```

In other words, don't think of this as "multiple group bys".  Think of it as a single aggregation where you get both the sum of the weights and the maximum value of `std`.

EDIT:

I seem to have misunderstood the question.  This is a bit of a pain in SQL lite.  Here is one method:

```
with w as (
      SELECT SUM(weight) as weight_sum, group, std
      FROM weight_table 
      WHERE combination_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
      GROUP BY group, std
     ),
     wmax as (
      SELECT group, MAX(weight_sum) as maxws
      FROM w
      GROUP BY gruop
     )
select w.group, sum(w.weight_sum) as weight_sum,
       max(case when w.weight_sum = wmax.weight_sum then std end) as std
from w left join
     wmax
     on w.group = wmax.group
group by w.group
order by weight_sum DESC;
```

Comment: He wants `std` based on the max `weight_sum`, which makes this a [tag:greatest-n-per-group], not a simple aggregate.